# Amzon Store Kindle Fire Compatibility

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I recently release an app for Kindle Fire. The app was approved by the amazon store, but was rejected for kindle. Following feedback was given :

***We have recently evaluated your app’s compatibility with Amazon’s Kindle Fire tablet. This added test process is here to verify that every app available for download on Kindle Fire will provide our customers with a high-quality experience on their devices. Your existing submission of XXXXXXXX has been found to be incompatible with Kindle Fire due to the following:
Upon completion of our compatibility test processes, your app was found to be unresponsive when subjected to testing. To be compatible with Kindle Fire, the app’s core features must be responsive to user commands, and its primary functionality accessible and compliant with device specifications.
Please review these issues and update your submission to address the incompatibility.  You may find it helpful to review the Kindle Fire FAQ in the Amazon Appstore Developer Portal.***

Has anyone got any pointers on what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Never developed for amazon, but the text seems to point out that your app freezes the user input in a certain situation.
Maybe there is some data retrieval that is not done in a separate process and freezes the ui?

Answer (score 0):

I just received the same response from them and, I to, have apps they approved for their store, tested on, based on the Flurry analytics I'm using, less powerful devices than the Kindle Fire.  It's pretty vague too, wish they offered a developer tablet or some more details.  Only thing you can do is maybe guess what is unresponsive and hope it passes next time.

Comment: I am searching contents in an xml, which takes a couple of seconds. I moved it  an AsycTask and resubmitted. Keeping Fingers crossed

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're getting [ANRs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html). Read tips on how to avoid this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html
but most of the time it's caused by doing something long running (usually network calls) on the UI thread. Make sure you spawn another thread being doing a network call.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Motorola Xoom running Honeycomb 3.2 you might want to test your app on that.  My app was rejected by Amazon because they experienced blank screens.  I've tested it thoroughly on Kindle Fire and have never seen that behavior.  It was only when I emphasized that point with the Amazon reviewer that I learned they were not testing on their own device but on Motorola's Xoom running an obsolete OS that I don't want to support.  I now have a Xoom and my app runs fine on it under ICS but is quite buggy with Honeycomb.